# Show changesets since last "get latest version"?

Tags: version-control, tfs, history

Using Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio 2008, is there a way to highlight the submissions since my last "get latest version"?  This would allow me to quickly identify what has been submitted since my last "pull" without having to remember which changeset I last synced with.

Thanks.

Eric

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click the file in the `Solution Explorer` and select the `Compare` option, in the pop-up window set the `Target Version` as `Type`: `Latest Version`.

Click `OK` and your comparer tool will open up showing the differences beteween your local file and the latest version in the server.